Why iframe enforce the parent page's Content Security Policy instead of its own
I’m working with an iframe and attempting to define its own Content Security Policy (CSP) using the csp attribute and the sandbox attribute. Here's the HTML structure of my iframe:
<iframe
  sandbox="allow-scripts"
  csp="default-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';"
  srcdoc="...myContent"
></iframe>

The issue is that scripts and styles within the iframe are still being blocked based on the CSP of the parent page, even though I explicitly define a csp attribute in the iframe itself. For example, the following script fails to load with an error:
Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-m5JxllYLAaAYeolMNX0mQg==' 'strict-dynamic'".

This restriction ('nonce-m5JxllYLAaAYeolMNX0mQg==' and 'strict-dynamic') is from the CSP of the parent page, not the iframe. My understanding is that the csp attribute on the iframe should allow it to enforce its own CSP rules and ignore the parent page's CSP.
Questions:

Why is the iframe still enforcing the parent page's CSP instead of its own?
Is there a way to fully isolate the iframe's CSP so it loads resources according to the policies defined in the csp attribute?
Is this behavior expected, or is it a bug or limitation in modern browsers?

Additional Context:

The iframe includes the sandbox="allow-scripts" attribute to isolate its context.
I am dynamically injecting content into the iframe using srcdoc and the csp attribute.


Does it behave the same, when the iframe content is not from a srcdoc, but loaded from a URL using src?

Unfortunately, I cannot use an external src because the content loaded through srcdoc is dynamic and originates from configurations provided by the user.

Friend, you should notice two things...
1st.: The sandbox attribute in the <iframe> tag is not related to CORS. It's related to the document capabilities. This means that if there's no allow-scripts, then the content of the <iframe> will not be able to run scripts.

iframe[sandbox="allow-scripts"]: Allows the page to run scripts (but not create pop-up windows). If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.
From MDN

2nd: The csp attribute in the <iframe> tag is experimental and will only enforce the CORS policy for the <iframe> contents.

A Content Security Policy enforced for the embedded resource.
From MDN

So, if you have an index.html with an <iframe> with those two attributes, then the index.html context will have it's CORS policy updated by the csp attribute only for the source of that <iframe>. This source will have its own CORS policy header (that is not affected by the csp attribute of the index.html file).
This happens because index.html can't change the target src CORS policy (if it can, then any site will be vulnerable to hackers).
If your <iframe> loads a content of the same-origin, then there's no need for those two attributes in the way you're using them (in my opinion).
So, the conclusion is that, as your <iframe> uses a srcdoc attribute, then it's probably inheriting the document CORS policy of the <iframe> element which the document can't change after setting the <iframe> element into itself, and yet, the context inside the <iframe> element (which is the srcdoc attribute value) will see the parent document CORS policy as defined in the csp attribute of that <iframe> element.

Why are you talking about CORS all over the place here? CSP and CORS are two very different things.
